# How to use Count condition in sql query

Tags: mysql

How can I use count condition in sql query. Here is my query

```
SELECT COUNT(test='maths') FROM homework where id = 1;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In MySQL conditions have either `1` or `0` as outcome. So use  `sum()` instead

```
SELECT sum(test='maths') FROM homework where id = 1;
```

`count()` just counts non-null values. So you could do it with `count()` too but like this

```
SELECT count(case when test='maths' then 1 else null end) 
FROM homework 
where id = 1;
```